# how to decompress my .gz file with extension

Tags: command-line, xml-parsing, gzip

gzip -d -f *.gz

When I run this,I couldnt see my xml files in .zip files. I just saw files without any extensions.

What is the reason ?

Comment: You need to provide more information in your question.  What .zip files?  Are you referring to the .gz files, or are there .zip files compressed into .gz files?  What exactly are you expecting that you are not seeing?  What is stored in the .gz files and how are they named?  What do you see if you do `gzip -lN *.gz` on the files?

Comment: Then either answer the question below yourself, which you can do and is encouraged, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

gzip -d -f *.gz

ren file_name* file_name*.xml

> > it is optional "ren" or "rename" .

You can use this : )